# Show that $\{ x | x \in P \text{ and } x \in Q \} $ exists

Tags: set-theory

I need to prove that the set $\{ x \,| x \in P \text{ and } x \in Q \}  $ exists. Now, I am thinking of [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). This axiom states that

$$ \forall w_1,\cdots, w_n \, \forall A \,\exists B \,\forall x \left( x \in B \Longleftrightarrow [ x \in A \wedge \varphi(x,w_1, \cdots , w_n, A)] \right) $$

Now, I will define predicate $\varphi(x, P, Q) = x \in P \text{ and } x \in Q $. Also, I will let $A = P$ and  $w_1 = Q $. So using universal instantiation, I get the following

$$ \exists B \,\forall x \left( x \in B \Longleftrightarrow [ x \in P \wedge \varphi(x, P, Q)] \right) $$

And using, existential instantiation, there exists a set $B$ such that

$$ \forall x \left( x \in B \Longleftrightarrow [ x \in P \wedge \varphi(x, P, Q)] \right) $$

Now, using [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), it follows that

$$ B = [ x \in P \wedge \varphi(x, P, Q)] $$

So, does this mean that $ B = \{ x \,| x \in P \text{ and } x \in Q \}  $ ?

Comment: On looking closely, it seems $B$ is indeed the set which I tried to prove exists.

Comment: You forgot here to specify that $P$ and $Q$ are already existing sets!